# Jax-rs Swagger integration - fetching resource list: http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-Example/rest/api-docs

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, wordnik

I am trying to integrate `JAX-RS` and `Swagger` together. While doing that I see following error is coming. After spending a lots of hours still I am not able to resolve it. Looking quick help from your end.

[image]

I've attached my whole source code in the git repository: **https://github.com/JavaNeed/JAXRS-Example**. Please try to resolve this error.

Comment: Please consider a modern version of swagger.  You are using 1.3.8 which is over 2 years old.  There are samples at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples that will help get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues integrating swagger and jax-rs. I finally got them resolved using jersey servlet implementation. See if following project helps you.

https://github.com/sanketsw/jax_rs_REST_Example

Also following link has the details of how to get JSON and YAML specification from JAX-RS API

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5